# How could I get a normal title image like twitter app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface

```
UIImageView *googleLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
        googleLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"googlelogo.png"];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = googleLogo;
```

[image]

Comment: May be your image size and frame size you defined is different, both the image size and frame should be same to get the proper result

Comment: If you still face the issue after setting both the image size and the frame size as equal, Let me know will help you out to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImageView *titleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 78, 20)];

[titleImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"google.png", nil)]];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImage;
```

set the size of the image based on your requirements

If your image size is **78 X 20** you have to set the frame that during initialisation.

May be your image size and frame size you defined is different, both the image size and frame should be same to get the proper result

Answer (score 0):

Change the image view mode that fit the image as button size will not stretch that image

```
googleLogo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```